# JqueryTools conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create this [tooltip sample](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/test.php) for my wordpress it works just fine but as soon as I integrated it in wordpress I can't get the tooltip to show up. The page where I want to work is [here](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/about-phil/team/)

ok I did a little experiment this is [test version](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/test.php)and this is the [wordpress version](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/about-phil/team/). The test version is the code when you do a view source a save it all and uploaded it and the tooltip worked! But the wordpress version doesn't work.. now that is both the same but one is working and the other one is not.

here is the JQuery codes:

**Header**

```
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.2/full/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

**Footer**

```
<script>
// What is $(document).ready ? See: http://flowplayer.org/tools/using.html#document_ready

$(document).ready(function() {

    // enable tooltip for "download" element. use the "slide" effect
    $("#download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'}); 
});
</script>
```

**and this is what Wordpress generates(this is from a view source)**

```
    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.1.2/full/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
            $j=jQuery.noConflict();   


            $j(document).ready( function() {
               initCalendar();
            });

            function initCalendar() {
                $j('a.prev-month').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    tableDiv = $j(this).parents('table').parent();
                    ($j(this).hasClass('full-link')) ? fullcalendar = 1 : fullcalendar = 0;   
                    prevMonthCalendar(tableDiv, fullcalendar);
                } );
                $j('a.next-month').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    tableDiv = $j(this).parents('table').parent();
                    ($j(this).hasClass('full-link')) ? fullcalendar = 1 : fullcalendar = 0;     
                    nextMonthCalendar(tableDiv, fullcalendar);
                } );
            }    
            function prevMonthCalendar(tableDiv, fullcalendar) {  
                if (fullcalendar === undefined) {
                    fullcalendar = 0;
                  }
                month_n = tableDiv.children('div.month_n').html();                                
                year_n = tableDiv.children('div.year_n').html();
                parseInt(month_n) == 1 ? prevMonth = 12 : prevMonth = parseInt(month_n,10) - 1 ; 
                if (parseInt(month_n,10) == 1)
                        year_n = parseInt(year_n,10) -1;
                $j.get("http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom", {ajaxCalendar: 'true', calmonth: prevMonth, calyear: year_n, full: fullcalendar}, function(data){
                    tableDiv.html(data);
                    initCalendar();
                });
            }
            function nextMonthCalendar(tableDiv, fullcalendar) {
                if (fullcalendar === undefined) {
                    fullcalendar = 0;
                  }
                month_n = tableDiv.children('div.month_n').html();                                
                year_n = tableDiv.children('div.year_n').html();
                parseInt(month_n,10) == 12 ? nextMonth = 1 : nextMonth = parseInt(month_n,10) + 1 ; 
                if (parseInt(month_n,10) == 12)
                        year_n = parseInt(year_n,10) + 1;
                $j.get("http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom", {ajaxCalendar: 'true', calmonth: nextMonth, calyear: year_n, full : fullcalendar}, function(data){
                    tableDiv.html(data);
                    initCalendar();
                });
            }

            // function reloadCalendar(e) {
            //  // e.preventDefault();
            //      console.log($j(this).parents('table'));
            //     $j.get("http://www.testground.idghosting.com/philcom", {ajax: 'true'}, function(data){
            //      tableDiv = table.parent();
            //      tableDiv.html(data);
            //             });
            // }
            //                      

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ONLY use the HTML editor and I write my own `<p>` tags and `<br />` and so forth... The problem I'm running into is that each time I use a special `<span>` with custom styling that I've made, WP is adding a `<p>` around that span as well as a `<br />` after the paragraph.

Now the solution is to have the Formating disabled in Wordpress editor by [downloading this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ps-disable-auto-formatting/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using $ instead of $j ?

```
<script>
// What is $(document).ready ? See: http://flowplayer.org/tools/using.html#document_ready

$(document).ready(function() {
 // enable tooltip for "download" element. use the "slide" effect
 $("#download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
});
</script>
```

Comment: where do i put that in? is this somewhat different to $j=jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: $j("#download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});  needs to be $("#download_now").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});

Comment: $j is for jQuery stuff, $ is for your jquery.tools stuff!

Comment: I added a script on the header see my updated post and the footer remains as it is.

Comment: I look at the web link you sent and I dont see any conflicts, if it doesnt work is something different.

Comment: Hi Ivo that is the problem nothing is different, I actually made a test I have updated my post with the test version and the wordpress version. The only difference with this is that with the test version it is the view source

Comment: What is not working more specifically, because at first you had jQuery namespace conflict and that is now resolved.

Comment: the 2 links "test version j(ust HTML)" and "wordpress version" in my post. If you rollover the dude in the test version it shows a tooltip, but in the wordpress version with the same code just doesn't work at all...